# Using Office-365-SDK-for-iOS

Tags: ios, azure, xcode6, office365, adal

I am integrating Office-365-SDK-for-iOS to fetch the user profile and contacts from outlook 365. I configure my application on azure management portal successfully. below are the constants for the app-

```
#define OutlookClientId @"11d21f9f-6b16-4ea9-8f73-bbc9a65ac72b"
#define OutlookAuthority @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/06cbda59-d75b-4547-8406-e6af3ff4c658/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0"
#define OutlookRedirectUrl @"http://localhost/MyAppName"
#define OutlookRsourceId @"https://graph.microsoft.com/"
```

When I am giving resourceId is https://outlook.office365.com/.

Then its giving me an error that this is not a valid resource id configured for the app.

I read many url to fined out the problem but I failed.These urls says that "If your app requires permissions to the Office 365 Mail, Calendar, or Contacts APIs, select the Office 365 Exchange Online service." but there is no this service to enable. Below is my add application page screen shot-

[image]
There are only 3 application to add.

Please help me out out on this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of account are you logging onto the Azure management portal with? Does it have access to Exchange Online? My guess is your Office 365 subscription doesn't include Exchange or SharePoint, so you don't see them there.

It looks like you're trying to use the Unified API though. In that case your resource ID should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/`.

Comment: Yes, I am using trial version. I don't have any subscription. I am using the same resource id as you given. But I need contacts and my information from outlook365.

Comment: I try this but no luck. it gives me the same error "Error Domain=Error in the Request Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Error in the Request error 401.)" I have bizspark subscription

Answer (score 1):

Ravi,
Please take a look at this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/get-started-with-office-365-unified-api

The resource for the unified API is https://graph.microsoft.com not the one that you mention above.

In addition, if you want to query mail, events, files, etc, the tenant you are using for development must have a valid Office365 subscription.

Finally, personal contacts (aka. contacts in Outlook) are not yet supported (coming soon), right now you can access organizational contacts using this request: graph.microsoft.com/beta/myOrganization/contacts